# How to give variables from one function to other

Tags: python, function, variables, global-variables

I have this code:

```
def dataExtractor():
    # ***
    # some code here
    # ***
    for tr in rows:
        cols = tr.findAll('td')
        if 'cell_c' in cols[0]['class']:
            # ***
            # some code here
            # ***
            stringed_list_of_params = [str(i) for i in (listOfParams[1],listOfParams[3])]
            numerical_list_of_codes_units = [int(i) for i in (listOfParams[0],listOfParams[2])]
            numerical_list_of_rates = [float(i) for i in (listOfParams[4])]
```

and I need to construct this function:

```
def calc():
    oneCurrency = (
            #digital_code[0]
            numerical_list_of_codes_units[0],
            #letter_code[1]
            stringed_list_of_params[0],
            #units[2]
            numerical_list_of_codes_units[1],
            #name[3]
            stringed_list_of_params[1],
            #rate[4]
            numerical_list_of_rates
            )
 # ***
 # some code
 # ***
```

But I can't access to `numerical_list_of_codes_units[0]` etc,
How can I give variables from one function to other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't "give variables", you either:

1. Pass *values* (i.e. objects) as parameters and return them; or
2. Share variables, usually by collecting functions together into a class.

Here's an example of 1.:

```
def dataExtractor():
    return somevalue

def calc(value):
    pass # do something with value

calc(dataExtractor())
```

Here's 2.:

```
class DataCalc(object):
    def dataExtractor(self):
        self.value = somevalue

    def calc(value):
        return self.value*2    
calc = DataCalc()
calc.dataExtractor()
calc.calc()
```

Comment: Great answer. But you probably meant to call `dataExtractor()` in the last line of the first example. Unless `calc` is supposed to take a function object as an argument and then call it itself, which is fine of course in Python and can be a very useful pattern.

Comment: @LukasGraf You're quite right, edited. Don't be shy about making edits when you find mistakes like that.

Answer (score -1):

You may make use of the `global` keyword. But, **you should almost always avoid the use of it**. When you declare certain variable as `global` it can be accessed by any function in that code. For example -

```
def f():
    global a
    a = 2

f()
print a
```

Output is

```
2
```

In your case, you should declare the list you want to use as global at the start of the function in which the list is generated. Following should do that.

```
def dataExtractor():
    global numerical_list_of_codes_units, stringed_list_of_params, numerical_list_of_rates
    # ***
    # some code here
    # ***
    for tr in rows:
    # rest of the code
```

Comment: Given that this question will be seen often by people new to programming, please at least include a strong warning against using `globals` in the answer.